# How to label tables automatically in R Markdown using numbers and letters?

Tags: r, pdf, latex, r-markdown

I have been trying to produce a pdf document in R Markdown, divided into many sections and subsections, and would like the tables to be numbered automatically. I´m using the following commands, which work fine with the kable function:

```
---
title: " "
output: bookdown::pdf_document2
header-includes: 
   - \usepackage[labelsep=space]{caption}
   - \counterwithin{table}{subsubsection}
   - \usepackage{longtable}
toc: yes
---
```

## Section

### Subsection

#### Subsubsection

```
library(knitr)

tab1 <- head(mtcars,3)
kable(tab1, booktabs = T, longtable = T, caption = ": Title1")

tab2 <- head(airquality,3)
kable(tab2, booktabs = T, longtable = T, caption = ": Title2")
```

It produces captions such as "Table 1.1.1.1".
My concern is that the amount of numbers in the table captions may get a bit confusing to follow.

**Question:** Is it possible to automatically produce captions such as "Table 1.1.1a" and "Table 1.1.1b", instead of "Table 1.1.1.1" and "Table 1.1.1.2", in cases when there is more than one table in a subsubsection?

Comment: Please make a [mre]

Comment: This is answered here:  https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/118606.  You redefine the `\thetable` macro.

Comment: What do you want if there's just one table in the subsubsection?  `1.1.1` would be hard, `1.1.1a` would be easy following the link I gave.

Comment: Ideally I´d like it to be 1.1.1, and have the letters only if there is more than one table in the subsubsection.